# why Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP) works

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I meet a lot of explanations about what CRTP is, but there is no explanation of why it works.

> The Microsoft Implementation of CRTP in ATL was independently discovered, also in 1995 by Jan Falkin who accidentally derived a base class from a derived class. Christian Beaumont, first saw Jan's code and initially thought it couldn't possibly compile in the Microsoft compiler available at the time. Following this revelation that it did indeed did work, Christian based the entire ATL and WTL design on this mistake.

For example,

```
 template< typename T >
 class Base
 {
    ...
 };

 class Derived : public Base< Derived >
 {
    ...
 };
```

I understand why and when it could be used. But I want to know how the compiler works in this way. Because in my head it shouldn't work due to endless recursion: class `Derived` inherits from `Base< Derived >`, where `Derived` is class which inherits from `Base< Derived >`, where `Derived`... and so on.

Could you please kindly explain step by step how it works from the compiler point of view?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recursively-defined types aren't unusual: a linked list is recursive, too. It works because at one point in the cycle you don't need the type to be complete, you only need to know its name.

```
struct LinkedNode {
    int data;
    LinkedNode *next; // Look ma, no problem
};
```

In the case of CRTP, that point is here:

```
Base<Derived>
```

Instantiating `Base` for `Derived` does *not* require `Derived` to be complete, only to know that it is a class type. I.e., the following works fine:

```
template <class>
struct Foo { };

struct Undefined;

Foo<Undefined> myFoo;
```

Thus, as long as the definition of `Base` does not require `Derived` to be complete, everything just works.

Comment: @JimBalter a counterexample could be a member whose type is defined in Derived, i.e. `template <class D> struct B { typename D::foo member; };`. That will fail to instantiate if `D` is incomplete at that point, and is thus not suited to a CRTP.

Comment: @JimBalter as for the linked list, if the compiler did not allow for a type to name itself in its own definition, it would have to look like `struct LN { int data; void *next; };` and you'd have to cast your way around from the outside.

Comment: @JimBalter I have no clue why you have to be so hostile, and I don't see how I could reformulate my answer in yet another way. Types can be complete or incomplete, and the CRTP *always* receives an incomplete type as parameter, that's it. In the exact same way, you can form a pointer to an incomplete type and use it in the definition of that same type, and that allows linked lists to work.

Comment: I can not understand that the object Base can call the non-static method of Derived whitout Derived Instantiating.
In my mind, the object Base does not have the method of Derived, but Why Base can call the method which belongs to Derived?

Answer (score 4):

The CRTP is named *recurring* because in

```
class Derived: public Base<Derived> { ... }
```

The class template `Base` is instantiated on the class `Derived`, which inherits from the class `Base<Derived>`, which is, in turn, the class template `Base` instantiated on `Derived`, which inherits `Base<Dervied>` ... and so on.

The name `Derived` above is used in its own definition, in a context where it is not yet fully defined, and, therefore, this makes `Derived` an *incomplete* type. `Base<Derived>` is being instantiated on a type, `Derived`, that is incomplete at that moment, so this is where the recursion ends since `Base` can't know that `Derived`, in turns, inherits from `Base<Derived>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Base< Derived >
```

Here, `Derived` only refers to a typename that's used for `T` inside `Base`, that's all it is. You certainly could get infinite recursion but that all depends on how you use `T` inside `Base` . `T` in itself is just a type like any other class type, types in itself don't actually do anything.

Comment: I can not understand that the object Base can call the non-static method of Derived whitout Derived Instantiating. In my mind, the object Base does not have the method of Derived, but Why Base can call the method which belongs to Derived?